# Growing tomatoes from seed in grow bags?

Tags: tomatoes, repotting

Is there any reason I can't just plant tomato seeds directly into grow-bags, without bothering with all the potting on palava?

Comment: Are you talking about store bought seeds or seeds you collected from a food tomato?

Comment: Store bought, @TimNevins.

Comment: My father used to do this.  Buy seeds and bags of soil.  Throw the bags of soil on the ground, next to the sunny side of the house.  Then, cut an X with a knife and throw seeds in the hole.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of germinating the seeds then potting on the little seedlings is to not expose them to too much fertilizer - seed and cutting potting soils have very little if any fertilizer in them so as not to burn the tiny roots as they start to grow and while they're very young. That won't be the case with the soil in your growbag, it will have a level of fertilizer within it suitable for larger plants.

Answer (score 1):

I think mostly the traditional practice is just to get the exact number of seedlings, and to optimize the germination conditions. Planting straight into grow bags should be fine.